# How to display a message on page using javascript after clicking on submit(input type) in a form without using PHP

Tags: javascript, html

How to display a message after clicking on submit in javascript without using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps

1. create a empty div to display error like below. set initial style as display : none

**Like Below**

```
<div id="msgDiv" class="message"></div>
```

2. On Submission of page just set innerHTML value to whatever message you want and  display inside  msgDiv div and apply style as display: block

**Like Below**

```
document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML = "Message ";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in your question (which message do you mean?), but this came me on mind:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(){alert("message");});
```

Comment: Your form has been submitted(Message)

Comment: @Prathiksha And how are you processing form?